# Report driven by SQL Command has stopped working

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

CR XI Developer R2. Version 11.5.12.1838, talking to Oracle 11.2.0.3 64bit

A report is driven by an SQL Command. It is (necessarily) a complex report consisting of 7 separate SELECT statements UNION ALLed together. The report also starts with a CTE (or whatever they're called in Oracle)

```
WITH MYCTE AS (
SELECT x, y, z 
FROM N)

SELECT ....
```

The SQL Command was edited thousands of times when under development. It was last changed six months ago.

Now when I edit the SQL Command, (Database Expert - Right click on Command - Edit Command  - Close I am greeted by the 'Map Fields' screen

[image: Crystal Reports 'Map Fields' screen]

which is telling me that my query doesn't have any columns in it, and well, proceeding further is useless.

It turns out that if the first line of the report is anything other than SELECT ... then this condition occurs. My environment hasn't changed, this report used to work, and now doesn't.

And it's a general thing as well. From scratch I created a report fed by an SQL Command that was

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

and it worked fine. Then I created another report fed by an SQL Command that was

```
/*This is perfectly valid SQL*/
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

Result was that no fields were found. I tried again (expecting failure, I wasn't disappointed) with

```
WITH STUFF AS (
    SELECT * FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM STUFF
```

Does anyone know what's going on? I wouldn't mind if SQL Commands didn't support CTEs, but they clearly do, because I managed to create / edit the existing report in the first place ....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Wow. It turns out it's a bug in the 11.2.0.3 Version of the oracle client installer. It OLEDb provider correctly. The fix is simply to run

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 <PathToYourOracleClientInstallFolder>\Client32bin\OraOLEDB11.dll
```

Actually found the answer at https://scn.sap.com/thread/3382251